# Sorting <li> elements of a <Ul> according to text in <span> inside <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a nested `<ul>` like `<ul>` with in `<ul>` and all `<li>` under `<ul>` have `<span>` in them. I want to sort all `<li>` items in alphabetical order according to text in their respective `<span>`

here is sample

```
<ul id="rootUl">
  <li>
   <span>zz</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>rr</span></li>
      <li><span>bb</span></li>
      <li><span>hh</span></li>
    </ul>
  <li>
   <span>kk</span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span>mm</span>
  </li>

 </ul>
```

root `<ul id="rootUl">` will always be there but all elements inside this `<ul>` are generated dynamically.

currently I am trying to get all `<ul>` under `<ul id="rootUl">` in array and pass them to sorting function one by one.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6tvzhkvk/2/

the expected result for given sample will be like

```
<ul id="rootUl">
  <li>
   <span>kk</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>bb</span></li>
      <li><span>hh</span></li>
      <li><span>rr</span></li>
    </ul>
  <li>
   <span>mm</span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span>zz</span>
  </li>

 </ul>
```

Comment: How do you determine where the `<li>` element containing the nested `<ul>` falls within the sort order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
// for each <ul> separately
$('#rootUl ul, #rootUl').each(function(_, ul) {

  // get all the nodes to be sorted
  var $toSort = $(ul).children('li').children('span');

  // extract the text
  var values = $toSort.get().map(function(span) {
    return span.textContent;
  });

  // sort the text
  values.sort();

  // shove reordered texts back into the original elements
  values.forEach(function(value, index) {
    $toSort[index].textContent = value;
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rootUl">
  <li>
   <span>zz</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>rr</span></li>
      <li><span>bb</span></li>
      <li><span>hh</span></li>
    </ul>
  <li>
    <span>kk</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>mm</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tvzhkvk/3/)

JS Code:

```
$('#sortTree').click(function () {
    var items = $('#rootul > li').get();
    var nestedItems = $('#rootul > li > ul > li').get(); 
    items = sort(items);      
    adjustItems('#rootul', items);
    nestedItems = sort(nestedItems);
    adjustItems('#rootul > li > ul', nestedItems);    
});

function sort(items) {
    items.sort(function(a,b){
      var keyA = $(a).text();
      var keyB = $(b).text();

      if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
      if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });       
    return items;
}

function adjustItems(sel, items) {
    var ul = $(sel);
    $.each(items, function(i, li){
      ul.append(li);
    });
}
```