# Sorting nested lists with jquery

Tags: jquery, list, nested

I am trying to sort nested lists. I came across this link: [Sorting <li> elements of a <Ul> according to text in <span> inside <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407964/sorting-li-elements-of-a-ul-according-to-text-in-span-inside-li)

It gets me most of the way there, however, it assumes you do not have lists like

```
<ul>
  <li><span>sortable text a</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>sortable subtext</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Whenever I use the code suggested above, any nested list gets appended to the first `<li>` in the nested list. I need it to go to the original list item.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // for each ul separately
  $('#rootUl ul, ul').each(function(_, ul) {
    // get all the nodes to be sorted
    var $toSort = $(ul).children('li').children('span');

    // extract the text
    var values = $toSort.get().map(function(span) {
      return span.textContent;
    });

    // sort the text
    values.sort();

    // shove reordered texts back into the original elements
    values.forEach(function(value, index) {
      $toSort[index].textContent = value;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rootUl">
  <li><span>zzz</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>dd zzz</span></li>
      <li><span>aa zzz</span></li>
      <li><span>bb zzz</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>ccc</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>ll ccc</span></li>
      <li><span>nn ccc</span></li>
      <li><span>mm ccc</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>rrr</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>ss rrr</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>dd ss rrr</span></li>
          <li><span>ff ss rrr</span></li>
          <li><span>ee ss rrr</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>rr rrr</span></li>
      <li><span>qq rrr</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would expect the following:

```
<ul id="rootUl">
  <li>
    <span>ccc</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>ll ccc</span></li>
      <li><span>mm ccc</span></li>
      <li><span>nn ccc</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>rrr</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>qq rrr</span></li>
      <li><span>rr rrr</span></li>
      <li><span>ss rrr</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>dd ss rrr</span></li>
          <li><span>ee ss rrr</span></li>
          <li><span>ff ss rrr</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>zzz</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>aa zzz</span></li>
      <li><span>bb zzz</span></li>
      <li><span>dd zzz</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But instead, I get this:

```
<ul id="rootUl">
  <li>
    <span>ccc</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>aa zzz</span></li>
      <li><span>bb zzz</span></li>
      <li><span>dd zzz</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>rrr</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>ll ccc</span></li>
      <li><span>mm ccc</span></li>
      <li><span>nn ccc</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>zzz</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>qq rrr</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>dd ss rrr</span></li>
          <li><span>ee ss rrr</span></li>
          <li><span>ff ss rrr</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>rr rrr</span></li>
      <li><span>ss rrr</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're just sorting the text of each span at the same level, you're not moving the rest of the `li` with it.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I'm not having any luck moving the rest of the li to its original <ul> tag. Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the `li` elements within their parent lists, not just move the text contents of the `span`s. Use a callback function in `sort()` that compares the text of the span.

Once you've sorted the `li`s, you can append them to their parent `ul` to rearrange them in the DOM.

It's also not necessary to specify both `#rootUl ul` and `ul` in the selector, since `ul` will match `#rootUl ul`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // for each ul separately
  $('ul').each(function(_, ul) {
    // get all the nodes to be sorted
    var $toSort = $(ul).children('li');
    $toSort.sort((li1, li2) => $(li1).children("span").text().localeCompare($(li2).children("span").text()));
    $toSort.each(function() {
      $(this).appendTo(ul);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rootUl">
  <li><span>zzz</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>dd zzz</span></li>
      <li><span>aa zzz</span></li>
      <li><span>bb zzz</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>ccc</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>ll ccc</span></li>
      <li><span>nn ccc</span></li>
      <li><span>mm ccc</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>rrr</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>ss rrr</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>dd ss rrr</span></li>
          <li><span>ff ss rrr</span></li>
          <li><span>ee ss rrr</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>rr rrr</span></li>
      <li><span>qq rrr</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's got it! Thank you!